# ArcPy: Initialize zero valued grid Raster and iteratively increment

Tags: python, arcpy

I'm jumping right into `ArcPy` to help out a friend who needs to automate some ArcGIS work. The problem at hand can be reduced to the following pseudocode:

```
accumulationRaster = SomeZeroedRaster
for each Raster pair, R, S, pertaining to rain and snow:   
   accumulationRaster += Con(S == 0, Con(R >= 1, 1, 0), 0)
```

In other words, iterate through all data of rain and snow of each day. Perform a logical operation on each cell pair, so that the corresponding cell in the `accumulationRaster` gets incremented if no snow (`S == 0`) and some rain `(R >= 1)`.

Having no luck so far with various attempts, I thought I'd ask here, as the problem should have an easy solution. Full working code with the missing gaps pointed out below. Most of it is just trivial file path set up, and the above pseudocode should suffice:

The missing pieces are numbered `1`, `2`, and `3`.

1. How to initializase a zero raster w/proper dimensions.
2. How to make a copy of this zero raster. If `1` is simple, just do this instead.
3. Increment accumulation raster.

---

```
import os
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

in_workspace = "C:/Data/ProjectFolder"
os.chdir(in_workspace)
arcpy.env.workspace = in_workspace

maaneder = ["01_januar", "02_februar", "03_mars", "04_april",
            "05_mai", "06_juni", "07_juli", "08_august",
            "09_september", "10_oktober", "11_november", "12_desember"]

################ 1 ###################
baseAccum = #1: ?? (zero Raster w/correct type & dimensions)
######################################

outputPath = "rainDaysInGrowthSeason/"
for year in range(1997,2015):
    for month in range(1, 13):
        ################ 2 ###################
        monthAccum = #2: ?? (Copy of baseSum)
        ######################################

        for day in range(1,32):
            # e.g 1997/09_september/
            fpath = str(year) + "/" + maaneder[month-1] + "/"
            # e.g. 1997_09_08.asc
            filesuffix = str(year) + "_" + str(month).zfill(2) + "_" + str(day).zfill(2) + ".asc"
            # e.g. Snoedybde/1997/09_september/sd_1997_09_08.asc
            snoefile = "Snoedybde/" + fpath + "sd_" + filesuffix
            # e.g. rrl/1997/09_september/rrl_1997_09_08.asc
            rrlfile = "rrl/" + fpath + "rrl_" + filesuffix

            hasSnoe = os.path.isfile(snoefile)
            hasRrl = os.path.isfile(rrlfile)
            if (not hasSnoe or not hasRrl):
                continue

            snoeRaster = Raster(snoefile)
            rrlRaster = Raster(rrlfile)

            ############## 3 #####################
            monthAccum = #3: ??
                         # something a'la:
                         # += Con(snoeRaster == 0, Con(rrlRaster >= 1, 1, 0), 0)
            ######################################

        # e.g. rainDaysInGrowthSeason/1997
        outputDir = outputPath + str(year)
        if (not os.path.isdir(outputDir)):
            os.mkdir(outputDir)
        monthAccum.save(outputDir + "/r_" + str(year) + "_" + str(month).zfill(2))
```

Comment: You may have more luck getting an answer on gis.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster to make a zero base raster.

if you wanted the raster to be 50 rows and 50 columns with a 1 meter resolution. you can do this.

```
import numpy

myArr = numpy.zeros(50, 50)

myZeroRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(myArr, arcpy.Point(355355, 3199277), 1, 1)
```

You can also convert a raster to a numpy array and then do your accumulations using one numpy array to another.

Or if you have Spatial analyst, you could use the tool create constant raster to create a zero based raster and then use the  math -> Plus tool to add your rasters together